# How to expand $df(xy)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If $f(z)$ is a single variable function(continuous and differentiable) with $z \in R ,z>0$ is there a way to expand this differential?? $$df(xy)$$ meaning if $z=x*y$ with $x,y>0$

$*$ is the simple multiplication.

Comment: What does expand a differential mean? You can consider the map $g(x,y)=f(x\cdot y)$ which is a two variable map, and compute its differential (I am not sure if this is what you meant).

Comment: for example $d(x*y)=xdy+ydx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentials satisfy the chain rule:

$$ \mathrm{d} f(u) = f'(u)\,  \mathrm{d} u $$

and they respect equations, such as $u = xy$:

$$ \mathrm{d} f(xy) = f'(xy) \, \mathrm{d}(xy) $$

so you'd get

$$ \mathrm{d} f(xy) = f'(xy) (x \, \mathrm{d}y + y \, \mathrm{d}x ) $$

And, incidentally, this equation still holds even if $x$ and $y$ are dependent on one another, and even if one (or both!) are constant!